# Pyspark: Container exited with a non-zero exit code 143

Tags: apache-spark, rdd, pyspark, spark-submit

I have seen various threads on this issue but the solutions given are not working in my case.

The environment is with pyspark 2.1.0 , Java 7 and has enough memory and Cores.

I am running a spark-submit job which deals with Json files, the job runs perfectly alright with the file size < 200MB but if its more than that it fails for **Container exited with a non-zero exit code 143** then I checked yarn logs and the error there is **java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Requested array size exceeds VM limit**

Since the json file is not in the format which can directly be read using **spark.read.json()** the first step in the application is reading the json as textfile to rdd to apply map and flatMap to covert into required format then using spark.read.json(rdd) to create the dataframe for further processing, the code is below

```
def read_json(self, spark_session, filepath):
        raw_rdd = spark_session.sparkContext.textFile(filepath)
        raw_rdd_add_sep =  raw_rdd.map(lambda x:x.replace('}{','}}{{'))
        raw_rdd_split = raw_rdd_add_sep.flatMap(lambda x:x.split('}{'))
        required_df = spark_session.read.json(raw_rdd_split)
        return required_df
```

I have tried increasing the Memory overhead for executor and driver which didn't help using options **spark.driver.memoryOverhead** , **spark.executor.memoryOverhead**

Also I have enabled the Off-Heap options **spark.memory.offHeap.enabled** and set the value **spark.memory.offHeap.size**

I have tried setting the  JVM memory option with **spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Xms10g**

So The above options didn't work in this scenario, some of the Json files are nearly 1GB and we ought to process ~200 files a day.

**Can someone help resolving this issue please?**

Answer (score 1):

1. Regarding `"Container exited with a non-zero exit code 143"`, it is probably because of the memory problem.
2. You need to check out on Spark UI if the settings you set is taking effect.
3. BTW, the proportion for `executor.memory:overhead.memory` should be about `4:1`
4. I don't know why you change the JVM setting directly `spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Xms10g`, I recommend using `--driver-memory 10g` instread. e.g.: `spark-submit --driver-memory 10G` (I remember `driver-memory` only works with spark-submit sometimes)
5. from my perspective, you just need to update the four arguments to feed your machine resources:

```
spark.driver.memoryOverhead , 
spark.executor.memoryOverhead, 
spark.driver.memory , 
spark.executor.memory
```

Comment: Hi , Thank you for the comment. I have tried to control the four config options given in your comment with various combinations but its not working.

Comment: did you check the Spark UI for the memory? and how many spark workers are you running? you can update your total cluster Cores and Memory in your question.